# Jquery Cycle2: Handling images and videos differently in the same slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have been using Cycle2 for an image slideshow on a website and I have been asked to add a video into the slideshow.

In my testing in a static html file, I have managed to get videos working thanks to the examples shown on the malsup.com website.

However I can't quite get the slideshow working how I would like it when it has a combination of images and videos.

When the slideshow was just images, I had this code in the slideshow call which works really nicely:

> data-cycle-delay="1000"
>   data-cycle-timeout="5000"
>   data-cycle-speed="900"
>   data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"

However, unless I change 5000 for data-cycle-timeout to 0 like below, the video only plays for a small amount of time before progressing to the next slide:

> data-cycle-timeout="0"

Is there a way with Cycle2 to have it behave differently for images and videos in the one slideshow?

Eg if an image, use this...

> data-cycle-timeout="5000"
>   data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"

If a video, use this...

> data-cycle-timeout="0"

Ideally any images in the slideshow would progress to the next slide after a count of 5000, whilst any videos would play their full length before progressing to the next slide.
    Eg Say you have a slideshow with the following content:

> ```
>    slide 1 = image (action: show for 5 seconds, then progress to next slide)
>    slide 2 = 5 minute video (action: show the full 5 minute video, then progress to next slide)
>    slide 3 = image (action: show for 5 seconds, then progress to next slide)
>    slide 4 = image (action: show for 5 seconds, then progress to next slide)
>    slide 5 = 3 minute video (action: show the full 3 minute video, then progress to next slide)
>    loop
> ```

Does anyone know how to achieve something like that with Cycle2?

The CMS is a MODx site, so most code should work.

Thanks in advance for any help.
(apologies for the bad formatting. I had trouble creating a fiddle, so I paste the full code of the test html instead...)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>Cycle2 YouTube</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>


<style>
.cycle-slideshow { max-width: 640px; margin: auto }
.cycle-slideshow > div { width: 100%; height: 100% }
.cycle-slideshow > img { width: 100%; height: 100% }
.cycle-slideshow > video { width: 100%; height: 100% }
iframe,object,embed { width: 100%; height: 100% }
</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="main">


<h2>Videos and Images</h2>

<div class="cycle-slideshow"
   data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
   data-cycle-timeout="0"
   data-cycle-delay="1000"
   data-cycle-speed="900"
   data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev2"
    data-cycle-next="#next2"
    data-cycle-slides=">a,>img,>video"
    data-cycle-youtube=true
    data-cycle-youtube-autostart=true
    >

    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg">

    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/f7AU2Ozu8eo?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0">Paul Irish</a>

    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg">

    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/seX7jYI96GE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0">Alex Russel</a>

</div>
<div class=center>
    <a href=# id=prev2>&lt;&lt;Prev </a>
    <a href=# id=next2> Next&gt;&gt;</a>
</div>


</div> <!-- #main -->



<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.video.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to manually recreate the autoplay functionality using Cycle2's API (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/). That would allow you to set the time per-slide and advance it based on events rather than a timer. Roughly, this is how I would do it:

First, give each slide a class or data attribute to differentiate between the ones that contain videos and the ones that contain images.

Start the slideshow paused using the `paused` option so it doesn't advance on its own

Create `cycle-initialized` (called when the slideshow is ready) and `cycle-after` (called after a slide transition) event handlers with the following logic:

Test to see if the current slide is an image or a video using the special class you added.

If it's an image slide, create a `setTimeout` that waits 5000ms and then calls `$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next')` to advance the slideshow

If it's a video slide, use the YouTube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) to hook into the player's `onStateChange` event. When the state changes to 0 (this means the video has ended), call `$('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next')` to advance the slideshow. You can't just set a timeout to the length of the video, because the user might pause the video or it might have to wait for buffering. You don't want it advancing mid-play!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello Ryan, Thank you for your response. That definitely sounds like it could work, your logic sounds great. Adding a class or data attribute to differentiate images and videos is a good idea. I can do that much. Then I am stuck! (I am not a programmer).
The video could be an html5 hosted video, youtube video (or vimeo I guess). I don't suppose you would have the time to create a fiddle for me? Or can I contact you directly to ask for a quote to prepare the files? (not sure if it is appropriate on stack exchange, sorry if not)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#slider').cycle({
  fx: 'scrollHorz',
  slides: '.slide',
  timeout: 6000,
  pagerActiveClass: 'active'
 });
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  .slide {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;

    &:first-child {
      display: block;
    }
    .slide-inner {
      position: relative;
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}

.video-wrap { 
  position: relative; 
  //slider resolution = 1600 x 650, so this percentage is from 650/1600=0.40625
  padding-bottom: 40.625%;
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
} 

.video-wrap iframe { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x650" class="slide-image" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- slide -->

  <div class="slide">
    <div class="video-wrap">
      <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lscb4SL58X4?enablejsapi=1"></iframe> </div>
  </div>
  <!-- slide -->
</div>
<!-- slider -->
```

Please refer this link for more details. I think which is useful

https://www.minddevelopmentanddesign.com/blog/create-a-responsive-youtube-video-slider/